# Prevent a LESS Mixin being applied if it is within itself?

Tags: css, less

I have a LESS mixin applied to a number of different classes. Its possible for one element with the mixin to be within another element which also have the mixin. When this is the case I dont want the child element to have the styling applied.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPBWXM

```
.style1() {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.elm1 {
  .style1;
}

.elm2 {
  .style1;
}


<div class="elm1">Element 1</div>

<div class="elm2">
  Element 2
  <div class="elm1">Element 1</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's more a CSS question rather than a Less (or specifically mixins) one so I added `css` tag. (Simply because it's not the mixin that really makes your HTML to work that way but the CSS selectors you use, thus it's more about modifying those selectors and not about modifiing the mixin itself).

Comment: I can't modify the html. If it was css it would be much simpler so I dont really agree that it's a css question.

Comment: Why would you need to modify the HTML?  You can't modify the LESS/CSS?  Because just adding `.elm1 > .elm2` and a reset undoing the CSS rules would work.  Otherwise, what you're talking about doesn't exist in LESS because it doesn't exist in CSS.  There is no parent selector in the (current) CSS framework.

Comment: I can modify the less. That html is a simplified example. Elm2 won't necessary be a direct descendant of elm1

Comment: Well, if you set some styles for `.elm1` they are supposed to apply to any `.elm1` element (that's what CSS is, and it absolutely does not matter if you set those styles via mixin or via Less at all). Hense this is about changing those **CSS** selectors you use ("changing CSS selectors" is not equal to "modify your HTML", for instance in a simple case you would need just to use something like `:not(.elm2) > .elm1` instead of just `.elm1`) therefore it's more a question of knowing of possible **CSS** selectors and the way they work (and it's barely related to the mixin above).

Comment: Something like font-size is inherited but a border, margin, drop shadow etc are not.

Comment: In other words, [here's](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/myjyOL?editors=110) one of possible solutions (and as you can see the mixin is absolutely irrelevant there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it appears this is not possible.